# Querying Logs and Access between two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to identify any activity by some of my users who have accessed the system beyond a time frame in MS Access.

I have two tables.

```
Table 1: Log    
----------    
userid     
date/time ------------- DATE TIME Format they accessed    
location -------------- where they accessed (full URL format) 

Table 2: Schedule    
-----------    
system URL ------------ Subdomain URL   
window start    ------- TIME format
window end    --------- TIME format
window day (days of the week when this window is applicable) - 1 - 7 where 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday.
```

How do I filter this out to identify those users who accessed the system beyond the window time?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Advise not to use "where" nor any reserved word as a field name. Show sample data and desired result and what you tried. What exactly is stored in "time" field - clock time or number for elapsed time?

Comment: Oh sorry. Didn't realize. I just type where on the sample was just thinking on the fly. 

Where they accessed is actually location.

Comment: In Schedule  table is there only 1 row for each user with a value like: `1-6` in the `windowday` column, or there are say 6 rows for each day (Sun-Fri)?

Comment: 1 row for each user, each access done. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to query with SQL using an inner join

```
--This line selects the fields that we want to take from the first table
SELECT table1.userID, table1.accessTime, table1.systemURL

FROM table1

INNER JOIN 

--where the urls are the same
ON table2.systemURL = table1.systemURL

--compare the dates to see if it accessed outside of the window
WHERE table1.accessTime<=table2.windowStart Or table1.accessTime>=table2.windowEnd;
```

But please next time let us know what you have tried

Comment: I think  the `and` should be an `or`

Comment: Thanks all. Sorry first time in forums. 

I've tried the inner join as well. But for some reason, it doesn't work. I'll try again. 

I think my struggle was on 

--where the urls are the same
ON table2.systemURL = table1.systemURL

Table2 system URL is a the first few characters of the URL. It's a subdomain. 

Whilst the Table 1 is a full detail one.

Comment: Thanks guys for commenting! 

I've updated the details of the tables. Sorry first time posting on Stack Overflow.  

For some reason I still couldn't get it right. I'llt ry to use the syntax you gave. T2 Locatio is Subdomain http://..... .com While T1 URL is http://................... .asp

Comment: For the tables when connection two statements SQL looks for things that are identical. So unless the URLs are an exact match in each case the query will not output any entries

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information provided, I might suggest something like:

```
select 
    t1.userid, 
    t1.[time they accessed], 
    t1.[where they accessed]
from 
    log t1 inner join schedule t2 on 
    t1.[where they accessed] = t2.[system URL]
where not
    t1.[time they accessed] between t2.[window start] and t2.[window end]
```

You may also need to test against `[window day]`, but I'm not sure how this is implemented in your database.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment. I'll try it out. UPdated the details of the table up top though. Will try it out. 

My issue is T2 System URL is the subdomain while the T1 where they accesed is a full on URL down to file name.